# When to Use a bridge table in a star scheme

Tags: database, data-warehouse, star-schema, snowflake-schema, star-schema-datawarehouse

I am struggling to know when to use bridge tables while designing star schemas. Is it safe to assume that if the attribute I am looking for is in a many to many relationship entities, then I will have to use a bridge table?

For example, if we want to measure the fact : total number of students against the “year” dimension, and the following structure is given:

Student (1–M) enrollments
Enrollments (M-1) offering

And the attribute “year” is under offerings.

Can I create a dimension table directly from offering, or do I have to use the bridge table “Enrollments” first?

Comment: Enrollment sounds like a fact, not a dimension.  It's normal that fact tables "bridge" dimension tables.

Comment: You need to determine what your fact table is here - Enrolments, Offers or something else. It sounds likely there will be multiple fact tables here. You then have to work out the granularity of your fact table. If you have bridge tables in your source data then you will probably have to do some work to push them into your fact tables. You would not want to have the bridge tables in your final data warehouse as is likely to be counter-intuitive to the users who are going to frame their queries.